# Doctrine 2. How to calculate difference between two datetime fields in querybuilder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I have to following tables:

```
Registration
    id int
    created datetime

Activity
    id int
    startdate datetime
```

Now I want to add this condition to my SQL query:

```
(Registration.created + 7 days) <= Activity.startdate
```

How can I do this in Doctrine 2? I prefer a database independent solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DATE_SUB was the solution. I used it with doctrine 2.1.

```
$EntityManager->createQueryBuilder()->expr()->gte("r.created", "DATE_SUB(a.startDate, 7, 'day')")
```